# Isolating $\theta$ in $y=L \sin\left[\cos^{-1}⁡\left(\frac{L_{AB}+x-r \sin⁡\theta}{L}\right) \right]-r \cos⁡\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

I isolated two equations with two unknown and ended up with this one equation and one unknown below:

$$y=L \sin\left[\cos^{-1}⁡\left(\frac{L_{AB}+x-r \sin⁡\theta}{L}\right) \right]-r \cos⁡\theta$$

Angle $⁡\theta$ is the unknown, but I'm stuck on how to isolate it here so I can get its exact value.

Anyone know how?

Comment: Look for closed form expressions for $\sin(\cos^{-1}...))$...

Comment: @JeanMarie I just looked it up. Didn't know sin[cos^(-1)(x)] = sqrt(1-x^2). I'll try that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use MathJax formatting for mathematical expressions. For any assistance see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference